# azure devops pipeline CopyFiles@2 task copy's files from agent A but DownloadBuildArtifacts@0 downloads the files to agent B

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

i have wired behavior with the copy files from hosted agent and then downloading them back to the same agent
looks like it copies the files from agent A but the same pipeline downloading them back to Agent B
with is in another machine doing another build job that is not related

Upload from ios_docker_142_linux_slave_1
[image]

Download back to different agent ios_docker_141_linux_slave_3 , why ?
[image]

```
 - task: CopyFiles@2
    inputs:
      CleanTargetFolder: 'true'
      SourceFolder: '$(Agent.HomeDirectory)/../${{parameters.Folderpath}}'
      Contents: '**'
      TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
```

Comment: Could you share the screenshot of your copyfiles task setting  here?  Besides, are you using [azure devops parallel jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops)

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT i added an update to the question, also, yes i using parallel jobs
i using 10 hosted agents , and 15 self hosted agent

i want it to be as 1 unit start and end with the same agent from the pool.

you can see all the pipeline here in the question :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64460219/azure-starting-2-self-hosted-servers-deliver-files-to-azure-managed-agent-both-i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an expected behavior if you are using parallel jobs. According to your screenshot, there are multiple jobs self-hosted connect , mac_agent, copy_back_files_to_self..

One agent one job at a time. If the agent is running a job, it will in busy status, and other jobs will look for idle agents to run . The parallel jobs is for running multiple jobs in multiple agents at a time.

To achieve what you want, you need to **specify detail agent in your YAML file**. The pool name needs to add to the `name` field, then you could add [**demands**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). You may try the following YAML Code:

```
stages:

- stage: Deploy

  pool: 

   name: AgentPoolName(e.g. alm-aws-pool)

   demands:

    - agent.name -equals Agentname (e.g. deploy-05-agent1)

  jobs:

  - job: BuildJob

    steps:

    - script: echo Building!
```

Comment: question if i use this strategy, how i calculate how many Parallel jobs i need to buy?
if each pipeline have 3 jobs and i have 5 build agents are working concurrently?
15 ? less ?
@PatrickLu-MSFT

Comment: @user63898 It's not the way to calculate how many Parallel jobs you need to use. You could take a look at our official doc -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops&tabs=ms-hosted#estimate-costs Besides, also refer this blog how it will effect your build time https://samlearnsazure.blog/2020/02/11/parallel-azure-pipelines-jobs/ Hope it helps.

Comment: i was reading the first link you gave and it left me very confused.
in each pipeline i have 3 jobs that are dependent on each other that is i need to run them one after the other. 
but i can have a build job that involves upload from self-hosted server to managed agent and then back to the same self-hosted server this called 1 build job. then i can have 5 like this running concurrently.
so I'm still confused .. how many should i set up?
@PatrickLu-MSFT

Comment: @user63898 `i have 3 jobs that are dependent on each other that is i need to **run them one after the other**` For this , you actually only need one job under this situation.  And then you want to  have 5 like this running concurrently.  You will need 5 parallel jobs.